# Visual Studio 2015 ordered test. How to use .runsettings

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I am having difficulty building an ordered test in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise (Update 1) and having the unit tests within the ordered test be able to reference my [.runsettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj635153.aspx#example).

Specifically, I need to access the `TestRunParameters` defined in the [.runsettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj635153.aspx#example) file.

In any of my test methods, if I access the [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.properties.aspx) of the [TestContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx), the properties I defined in the [.runsettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj635153.aspx#example) are not found.

Surely I'm not the first to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same behavior, most of the time.  About one out of 5 executions, my properties from my runsettings file are present in the TestContext Properties dictionary.  I have yet to be able to consistently make it work.

Comment: I am having this issue (VS2015 Update 3).  the answer from BrettJ did not fix.  I have the correct run settings file loaded.  I did clean/build.  If I run an individual test, everything works and properties are loaded.  If I run an ordered test, the properties are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the bug in Visual Studio.  Whenever you select a runsettings file in the VS->Test->Test Settings submenu, they do NOT take effect until I at least do a Rebuild of my Test project (or a Clean solution / Build solution).  Simply building does NOT make VS apply the proper runsettings file.  There were certain situations where it wasn't applying any runsettings file, but since I started doing a Rebuild Project every time I select a different runsettings file, I've never discovered the TestContext *not* having my Proerties.