# runsettings' DeploymentEnabled flag not taken into account in Ordered Tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mstest, ordered-test

For some reason, the `DeploymentEnabled` flag is not taken into account *when I run my tests from an* `orderedtest`; i.e., the `DirectoryPath` is as if `DeploymentEnabled` was `True`, although I explicitly set it to `False` in the `.runsettings` file.

My question seems to be closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911935/visual-studio-2015-ordered-test-how-to-use-runsettings) although no solution was found there.

I run VS Enterprise 2015.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that, by design, ordered tests ***need*** files to be deployed to work.

Hence, I added similar code everywhere needed in my unit test classes:

```
<TestMethod()>
<DeploymentItem("Test Files\MyInputFile.txt", "Test Files")>
Public Sub ...
```

In my .runsettings file I set `DeployementEnabled` to `True`, and it works. The downside being I had many unit tests to update with `DeploymentItem` ...

[From Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx):

> In an ordered test, each test is self-contained and independent. So
>   the environment state is not retained between each test that is run.

I guess that answers the question.